# Gitignore for ionic project created using ionic start myproject sidemenu ignores platforms

Tags: ios, git, ionic-framework

When an ionic project is created using :

ionic start myproject sidemenu

The following gitignore is created

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
*.log
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
log.txt
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.vscode/
npm-debug.log*

.idea/
.sourcemaps/
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
hooks/
platforms/
plugins/
plugins/android.json
plugins/ios.json
www/
$RECYCLE.BIN/

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Why is platforms in gitignore? If the xcodeproj is built and we add AppIcons to it, those changes would be lost?

Is there any other way of adding AppIcons to an ionic project so that it builds into the xcassets assets catalog automatically?

Answer (score 1):

According to project structure, your images are stored in `resources/<platform>/icon` and `resources/<platform>/splash` folder.
These are copied over to your platforms during build time. You can save them there and this folder is not included in gitignore.

The file names of your resources to be copied are present in config.xml.

Generally create a single icon.png (1024×1024px) and splash screen : splash.png(2732×2732px) in resources folder in your project.

You can run

```
 ionic cordova resources
```

which will upload the images and create all your icons and splash screens for both platforms and saved them in the folder paths I mentioned as well as update the same in config.xml. Command info [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/) with options of `--splash` and `--icon`